# MySQLi and OOP PHP Error

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Login-OOP\classes\class.user.php on line 28
```

The above is the error I get, my class.user.php is:

```
<?php
class Users {
    public $db;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "<removed for privacy>", "oop");
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username=$username AND password=$password");
        $stmt->bind_param('ss', $username, $password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($username, $password);
        $stmt->store_result();
        if($stmt->num_rows == 1) {
            while($stmt->fetch()) {
                $_SESSION['username'] == $username;
                header("Location: home.php");
                exit;
            }
        }
        else {
            header("Location: index.php?e=invalidlogin");
            exit;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $stmt->free_result();
    }
    $this->db->close();
}
?>
```

So, is there anything that can be done? I am trying to access my index.php so, if you need my index.php, here it is:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    include "classes/class.user.php";

    if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
        extract($_REQUEST);
        $login = $users->login($username, $password);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="" name="submit">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="password" name="password">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope there is a solution for this error, I think this is a weird error. Can you suggest what has caused this error? Also if I am using any of my code in an in-secure way, please let me know to improve my habits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made mistake here. `$this->db->close();`

try to close database connection in `destructor`

```
public function __destruct() 
{
    $this->db->close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Move this `$this->db->close();` inside your  `public function login($username, $password)`

which is...

```
$stmt->free_result();
           }
           $this->db->close();
           }
         ?>
```

to

```
           $stmt->free_result();
           $this->db->close();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks alot, but it wont let me tick your answer. :[

Comment: @user3152750 Wait for couple of minutes.

Comment: Sorry, i have a better answer below.